# Closed form of the series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Write the following series in closed form
>   $$\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{2}{a-2}+\frac{2}{a-3}+\frac{1}{a-4}+\frac{1}{a-5}+\frac{2}{a-6}+\frac{2}{a-7}+\frac{1}{a-8}+\frac{1}{a-9}+\frac{2}{a-10}+\frac{2}{a-11}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a-4p+3}+\frac{2}{a-4p+2}+\frac{2}{a-4p+1}+\frac{1}{a-4p},$$
>   where $a$ is any positive number.

I tried to split this series into 4 sub series as follows

$$\frac{1}{a-1}+\frac{1}{a-5}+\frac{1}{a-9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a-4p+3}+$$

$$+\frac{2}{a-2}+\frac{2}{a-6}\frac{2}{a-10}+\cdots+\frac{2}{a-4p+2}+$$

$$+\frac{2}{a-3}+\frac{2}{a-7}+\frac{2}{a-11}+\cdots+\frac{2}{a-4p+1}+$$

$$+\frac{1}{a-4}+\frac{1}{a-8}+\frac{1}{a-12}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a-4p}$$

but still unable to obtain the result.

Comment: What makes you believe that it converges?

Comment: I think, your split looking good. you see in every row there is a difference of $4$. I mean $(a-j)(a-i)=4,\forall j>i$ for every row.

Comment: @Nyfiken this series gives a number for finite graph. So, it must be convergent.

Comment: I would do for the first row: $$\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \frac{1}{a-(4i+1)}$$

Comment: @serge thank you. But, can we obtain better expression I mean without summation?

Comment: Well, I put it in Wolfram alpha, and get an expression with the digamma function. I think it is not the result you are searching for.

Comment: and for $p\to\infty$ it is not converges. Because $\sum_{\mathbb N} \frac{1}{n}$ is divergent

Comment: Finally, I have: $$\frac{1}{a-4p}+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (\frac{1}{a-(4i+1)}+\frac{2}{a-(4i+3)}+\frac{2}{a-(4i+2)}+\frac{1}{a-4i})$$

Answer (score 0):

You have splitted the series in $4$ subseries. We see that for each sub series $(a-j)(a-i)=4,\forall j>i$. So we get the following series for every sub series:
$$(1):\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \frac{1}{a-(4i+1)}\\(2):\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\frac{2}{a-(4i+2)}\\(3):\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}\frac{2}{a-(4i+3)}\\(4):\sum_{i=0}^{p}\frac{1}{a-4i}.$$ Together in one expression we get:$$\frac{1}{a-4p}+\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{1}{a-(4i+1)}+\frac{2}{a-(4i+3)}+\frac{2}{a-(4i+2)}+\frac{1}{a-4i}\right)$$